# Failed to start DevTools: Dart DevTools exited with code 255

Tags: flutter

I am getting this error code in my Visual Studio Code. How can I fix it?

I am using Flutter v2.5.3.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to  SO. Have you installed dart extension using extensions panel?

Comment: Yeah, dear, I have installed the flutter extension in my vscode, and it's automatically installed the dart extension with it. Both are enabled.

Comment: Same issue pops up for me today

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can try fixing it by running this in the terminal:

Just copy and paste the below code into the terminal and run it.

```
dart pub global activate devtools -v 2.8.0
```

which downgrades the version to 2.8.0 (that works fine). I found the answer on [GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/3549#issuecomment-998961200).

Comment: I'm not sure why but I have to use this command every single time I open VSCode

Comment: @AryanSethi me too, I'd like to nuke the entire pub-cache to try to fix it once and for all but not sure about it.. I cannot find other solution from the internet

Comment: @Zennichimaro are you using FVM? because I am and I suspect that it might be the reason that we have to redo that every single time.

Comment: Here's a deeplink to the [comment indicating](https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/3549#issuecomment-998961200) that package version 2.9.2 was retracted from pub.dev

I therefore just deleted the folder it was downloaded into (~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/devtools-2.9.2/ in my case) and that solved the problem permanently.

Comment: @AryanSethi what is FVM? I've never heard it before so I don't think I use it..

Comment: @AryanSethi btw, I solved the problem permanently too by following this guide: https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/3549#issuecomment-1003026698

Comment: @Zennichimaro fvm is a package for Flutter Version Management. It helps you keep separate channels and versions of flutter for easy switching. And thanks for the link. I'll try it out too.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with [RandomCoder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70446275/failed-to-start-devtools-dart-devtools-exited-with-code-255/70459943#70459943) to avoid executing command

```
dart pub global activate devtools -v 2.8.0
```

every time before opening Visual Studio Code.

And also if you didn't know the location of the build folder mentioned by RandomCoder, I found the location after reading it [here](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/environment-variables) for the pub cache folder:

> By default, this directory is located under . pub-cache in your home directory (on macOS and Linux), or in %LOCALAPPDATA%\Pub\Cache (on Windows). (The precise location of the cache may vary depending on the Windows version.)

After you found it, go to the *\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\devtools-2.8.0* directory to copy the build version there and paste it in *\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\devtools-2.9.2*.

I still didn't know if there is any bad effects of copy pasting it to a newer version folder, but in my case it's working until now.

Comment: This is the fix that worked for me. 

Just running `dart pub global activate devtools -v 2.8.0` doesn't work if you use VSCode because the VSCode Dart extension seems to "upgrade" devtools back up to 2.9.2, causing the error to reappear.

Answer (score 4):

In my case there wasn’t any build folder in the *devtools-2.9.2 folder*.

I copied it from 2.8.0 and it now works.

Comment: To find the desired path in Windows, go to:
`C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\`

Answer (score 3):

I fix this by:

```
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue coming since yesterday. Maybe they must have updated the Dart engine.

There are two ways which will help you to solve the issue.

1. Update the Flutter SDK to the latest version and restart your PC:

   ```
   flutter upgrade
   ```
2. Use the Dart Devtools manually

   Run `flutter pub global` in another terminal. Run devtools and then open [http://127.0.0.1:9100](https://127.0.0.1:9100)

   Enter a running application field address of your running application in the Connect: "http://127.0.0.1:60230/J7_wS_YhTuo=/"

You can find this URL in debug console when you run the code.

√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:51849/mHlycLJYEWw=/ws

If you are getting any issue regarding the port, then do this in your Flutter project console

```
flutter run --observatory-port=9100
```

Once the application starts you can see the message in the console.

**If you are getting any server issue in the web browser
then enter**

```
dart devtools
```

**In cmd**

Comment: "maybe" and "must have" are contradicting words ;)

Comment: On [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes its for widows

Answer (score 2):

1. Downgrade to *devtools-2.8.0*
2. And activate using `dart pub global activate devtools -v 2.8.0`
3. These two steps worked in my case

Comment: How is that different from previous answers?

Answer (score 1):

First *activate* your devtool using this command...

```
flutter pub global activate devtools
flutter pub global run devtools
```

And after that, try launching it from Visual Studio Code as described in the documentation: *[Install and run DevTools from VS Code](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/vscode)*